# Flashgun for Nikon D60 and F5

Tags: nikon, equipment-recommendation, flash, film

So, I'm a massive fan of Nikon gear.  I've got a D60 which is pretty lovely, and I've recently bought a 2nd hand F5.

However.  The flash on the D60 is feeble, and there's no builtin flash on the F5.

I would like, a flash that works well on auto modes on both cameras, and will be "futureproof" to allow me to change up to the D7000 body in a few months time.

I was thinking of either the Metz 36 or Metz 48 flashguns.  I'd like a Nikon Speedlight, but they're Really Expensive.

I'd like to buy next week sometime, in time for an event coming up at the end of the month, so fast answers would be appreciated.

Comment: In the end, I actually bought the Jessops 360AFDN, because it was on offer, 3 days before I was due to go away.  It's Fantastic.  No complaints,  TTL just works, bounce flash, sync, etc.. All good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I happened to go into LCX today as my new tripod had arrived and asked your question on the off chance. They pretty much reflected what was said above i.e. the [SB600 (<200 GBP)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Nikon-B0002EMY9Y-SB-600-Speedlight/dp/B0002EMY9Y) would work very well with all three cameras you specified in auto modes and is a reasonable price, but if you wanted something more feature rich the SB900 (350 GBP) would do the job.

They also said that virtually all new flashes are backwards compatible, so I have the impression that you could buy any recent nikon hot shoe flash and it would work for the bodies you want it to. I'm sure they can help you out if you give them a call.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Woo! Thanks for asking on my behalf!  You win the +50 bonus

Answer (score 1):

What about using an SB 600 from Nikon? Same price as the Metz 48.... I have a few of these... they work great on a D200 and D300. When you can afford to step up I'd recommend an SU 800 wireless controller to control SB 600.

Comment: http://www.warehouseexpress.com/buy-metz-48-af-1-digital-nikon-fit-flashgun/p1023531 vs http://www.warehouseexpress.com/buy-nikon-sb-600-speedlight-flashgun/p13353 .. Metz is £54 cheaper.

Comment: Funny- at B and H the Metz is ten dollars more!

Answer (score 0):

This may not help but I've found [London Camera Exchange](http://www.lcegroup.co.uk/) to be very helpful from an advice and kit point of view, they have a wide variety of new and second hand kit available and almost all the second hand gear from any one shop is available online or at any other shop - they may be able to recommend something, the manager at the shop on [The Strand](http://www.lcegroup.co.uk/Branch.asp?Branch_ID=35) is very knowledgeable and helpful.

Reading back this comes off like an advert but it really isn't!

Comment: I'll check that out later perhaps.